# Why can't i declare a variable and store in if condition of my google captcha?

Tags: php, php-7

> When I try to declare a variable inside this if -else condition ,it
>   cannot be used afterwards (if else loop)

the var_dump() of the variable gives null , i tried initialising the variable before the condition , then var_dump gives the initialised value

```
/*code section start here
*/
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
         {
            $secret=get_option('googlerecap_clientsecret');
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
            if($responseData->success)
            {
    $somevariable="verified";
        $query2   ="UPDATE table_name SET captcha='Verified' WHERE id='".$insert_id."'";
        $success2 = $link->query($query2);
            }else{
    $somevariable="Not verified";

    }

        }

    var_dump($somevariable); // gives NULL a
```

Answer (score 1):

If the $_POST variable g-recaptcha-response is not set you will leave the condition immediately. Since you set both "verified" and "not verified" within this condition your variable will still be NULL if g-recaptcha-response is not set.
You have to place `$somevariable="Not verified";` before the condition to have a fallback.

Comment: I am very sure that  $_POST variable g-recaptcha-response is  because the update query in the same if condition is executed

Comment: Can you check it with `var_dump($_POST)`? Maybe there is some other issue with that variable. Another try: put `$somevariable="verified";` below the query execution.

Comment: Yeah i did that too var_dump() of that was also NULL

Comment: Are there any other script parts you didn't share about writing / reading that variable? What happens if you place `$somevariable="test"; var_dump($somevariable);` at the very beginning of your PHP file? At least that should work - if not your PHP installation may be corrupt.